# How to reach better performance in Looker?

Tags: visualization, derived-table, looker

I'm currently on a Looker project, in the model in one of the explorers there are many joins that pull a lot of information, but as the customer says, this is just the beginning. I don't understand how to unload it, persist doesn't help, I tried to make a data_group.

Now I’ve picked up the PDTs, but I don’t understand how they can be implemented if i font have a querie. It is possible only through lookML to pull out a delay table or a sql that the looker has generated based on what we have in the look.

The looks like a regular table with 8 fields, it takes a long time to open, I tried to comment on unused dimensions and measures, I tried to delete those joins on which we do not depend, nothing comes out .... a fresh look may be needed

Comment: mysql and google bigquery are two different products. Which one do you use?

Comment: I use LookML but this stack depend from BQ

Comment: @Shadow, I'd rather listen to your answer than fix the tags....

Comment: Tags **are** important! I only looked at your question because it was tagged as mysql. I know mysql pretty well, but I do not know much about BigQuery, nor looker. Most answers here on SO are the same: they look for questions tagged with programming languages / technologies they are expert in.